# Comparator in PriorityQueue vs ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, priority-queue, comparator

I have been trying to implement PriorityQueue.

Here is what I wanted, sort according to the length of the `String`.

```
static class abc implements Comparator<String>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return a.length() - b.length();
    }

}
```

And the main Function:

```
    List<String> q = new ArrayList<String>();
    q.add("1");
    q.add("0111");
    q.add("11");
    q.add("151");
    q.add("121");

    Collections.sort(q, new abc());
```

This gave the perfect result.

But, when I used PriorityQueue instead of ArrayList

```
PriorityQueue<String> q = new PriorityQueue<>(10, new abc());
```

I don't get the required result.

When I print PQ:

```
System.out.println(q.toString());

[1, 151, 11, 0111, 121]
```

Also, since I want my List to be sorted overtime when I add a string, I would prefer PQ over ArrayList.

Can someone show with some example how to achieve this?

Thank you:)

Comment: What result do you get via priorityQueue?

Comment: `PriorityQueue` will let you _extract_ elements in sorted order with `poll()`, but iterating over it or calling `toString()` on it will not return your elements in sorted order.  This is part of how a priority queue works.

Comment: Ohh, I got it.. Thanks

Comment: Have you considered a `TreeSet`, or can your collection contain duplicates?